# Code not recognizing "#include" statements

Tags: c++

I'm writing some header files for a project, but for whatever reason, I'm getting the error "Identifier ' ' is undefined. What am I doing wrong? (It won't recognize string or Boolean as correct)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Camper {
private:
    string name;
    boolean paid;
public:
    void setName(string);
    void getName() const;

    void setPaid(boolean);
    void getPaid() const;

    void display() const;
};
```

Comment: It's `std::string` and `bool`

Comment: Alternate:  on the line after "#include < string >" add  "using std::string;".  A comma list can be used for std=c++17 or later, such as "using std::string, std::to_string;".  Avoid "using namespace std;".

Comment: Aren't you missing using namespace std;

Comment: @AdanVivero writing `using namespace std;` in the header is a really bad idea.

Comment: @t.niese why? I do it all the time, and nothing bad happens.

Comment: @AdanVivero You have gotten lucky. Sooner or later you will have an identifier with the same name as something in the std namespace and you'll get a really nasty shock. [More on that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Putting `using namespace std` in a header spreads that pain to anyone who includes the header.

Comment: @AdanVivero You should not use `using namespace` in the header in general, and especially not for `std`. The `std` namespace contains a huge amount of function names that are commonly used in other libraries as well. Namespaces exists to minimize the risk of naming conflicts. If you now place a `using namespace` in a header, then all file that directly or indirectly include that header loose that protection, and in combination with other libraries it can result in hard to debug compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

Booleans are actually typed as `bool` in `c++`.Also the reason it wont recognize string is that `string` is part of the `std namespace`.You either need to add `using namespace std;` under your includes,or else you need to adress `string` as `std::string`.Some more elements from the `std namespace` are Vector,List,etc.You can take a look at those [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/)

EDIT:Also I just noticed your getter/setter methods.A `getter` method is used so you can access Object attributes without them being public,it returns a type of that attribute.If you want to access name described as an `std::string` your method should return `std::string`.Meaning your 2 getters should look like this:

```
bool getPaid() const;
std::string getName() const;
```

As L.F. pointed out it is not good practice to use namespaces as it can lead to confusing or even conflicting code.The reference is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: [I would not recommend `using namespace std;`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thats a good point,I didn't want to overwhelm him with information.I will edit that in just in case @L.F.